# How to skip to specific word in a string

Tags: c#

I stored variable string1 to a Text file and "&&" then the variable string2.

```
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login.txt", this.username.Text + "&&" + this.password.Text);
```

Txt file now containing variablestring1&&variablestring2.

I need to read string from Txt file and skip to word && (read the words before and after "&&")

Can any one help me with code pls ?

i tried this but not working ..

```
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login-info.txt"))
        {
            string[] array = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login-info.txt").Split(new string[]
            {
                "&&"
            }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            this.username.Text = array[0];
            this.password.Text = array[1];
        }
```

Comment: Search for `String.Split` and read about arrays and how to access them to get the strings at a specific index.

Comment: if the file just contains "variablestring1&&variablestring2" then you can use `"variablestring1&&variablestring2".Split(new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: yea the file will contain just varstring1&&varstring2 like "admin&&1234" then now to get string "admin" ? and to get string "1234" how ?    `File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login-info.txt").Split(new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: @Charles `Split("&&")` will be fine - SSO is optional

Comment: i need each one on its own. admin and 1234

Comment: Split will return you an array. "admin" is in `array[0]` and "1234" is in `array[1]`

Comment: If you control both writing and reading, why don't you use a simpler format ?

Comment: Since `password` can contain `&&`, `Split(new string[] { "&&" }, 2);` - note **2** - we want just one split and no more then *two* chunks. Another possibility is `IndexOf(&&)` and then `Substring`

Comment: can i from first store varstring1 in first line of the txt file then varstring2 in the second line and use `string logintxt = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login-info.txt").First();
    string passtxt = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\info\\login-info.txt").Skip(1).First();`

Comment: Read the file twice, you mean? You're making this very complicated

Comment: Why don;t you just use whatever applicable settings system your project has? Also.. **don't store passwords in plain text**

Comment: bro this is for fixing everytime run the program, user need to write his username and pass to login ,i do this to picked up the username and password from text file when the form load

Comment: @Caius Jard ok bro then how can i store it in registry ?

Comment: registry isn't any safer by any means. you have to "encrypt" it.

Comment: i already made online login system but as i told , everytime run the program, user need to write his username and pass to login how can i fix this ?

Comment: Online as in web browser? It's not your problem to store it; let the browser do it. If you're going to pre fill the username and password box in the page you send to the browser you might as well not bother having a login system at all

Comment: If you;re asking because you're trying to create a login system for an online site, again I wouldn't bother; all the Visual Studio online app templates come with skeleton code to use some auth system, be it database, windows, active directory.. you just click a few checkboxes and bam, working, secure login system

Comment: first time the user run the program register his username and password , then every time will open the program again need to write his username and password to login i need to store the user and pass in the txt file after clicking register and when form load auto fill this username and password

Comment: Please go and read some stuff about creating a secure login system.

Comment: lol i will store user in one file and pass in other txt file then File.ReadAllText

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your code should work. But this will fail if the username or password contains '&&', you will end up in more strings in the 'array' after splitting.
I suggest you to keep username and password in separate lines and keep the password encrypted using any algorithms like RSA or MD5. Then you can easily read the file content and the first line will be username, and the second line will be the encrypted password.
The file will look like,

```
admin
EncryptedPassword
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as your string can be read. It should have no problem.

[See.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vf0mxh)

Thanks.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string phrase = "username=The quick&&password=asdasdasdasdad";
        string[] words = phrase.Split("&&");

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string phrase = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/Resources/info/login-info.txt");
                string[] words = phrase.Split("&&");` cannot convert from string to char

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi 021, please use dotnetfiddle.net and provide a link to the code, this facilitates debugging.